# Python-Loops, nested loop

Tags: python

```
i for range(10)
   j for range(10+i,end)
   print(j,end="")

10
11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18,19
20,21,22,23,24
25,26,27,28,29,30
31,32,33,34,35,36,37
38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45
46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
```

i have been working on this since yesterday and cant seem to figure out. Perhaps I am over thinking it but i have literally tried everything

I know this is a basic question but i am new to python and need help. I have been looking this up today. I understand how the ranges work but cant figure out how to get the numbers to increase in this pattern –

Comment: This code has several syntax errors.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @kishinmanglani: achieve the posted output, at a guess and a quick glance at the (better worded) dupe.

Comment: Why didn't you paste your actual Python code? It should be almost the same as the pseudo-code.